# How to check input field's length?

Tags: jquery

How am I able to check input field's length?

For example, how to check if name entered in `input` field has `length` bigger than `2` characters?

Here is the code that I tried to use, but `length` always returns `0`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     name = $("#name").val();
     $("#name").change(function () {
         if (name.length <= 2) {
             console.log(name.length);
             $("#name").addClass("error");
         } else if (name.length > 2) {
             $("#name").removeClass("error");
         }
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put the `name` assignment inside of the `change` event.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#name").change(function () {
         var name = $("#name").val();

         if (name.length <= 2) {
             console.log(name.length);
             $("#name").addClass("error");
         } else if (name.length > 2) {
             $("#name").removeClass("error");
         }

     });
 });
```

...or here is a different way of writing it...

```
$(function() {
    $('#name').change(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('error', this.value.length <= 2);
    });
});
```

Comment: Cheers! That helped! I will accept as soon as possible. Maybe you could help me with another thing? How can I put some text between the <label> tags? I tried to do it with .val, but it didn't do anything.

Comment: Wow! Nice ;)! Gonna use the second one ;)!

Comment: @VdasDorls Use the `text()` method once you've selected the `label` elements. Glad you like the second example. :)

Comment: Okay, thanks! You can wait for accept in 4 minutes! Thank you again ;)!